# Why does function not support comparison operations? - [python]

Tags: python

I created a multiple choice quiz in python and at the end the program prints out a comment based on the score that the user got. But when I run the code, the system tells me "Type error: '>=' is not supported between 'function' and 'int'. This is my code:

```
trivia = [
    {
        "question": "111?\nA: a\nB: b\nC: c\nD: d\nE: e\n",
        "answeris": "A",
        "hint": 'h1'
    },
    {
        "question": "222?\nA: a\nB: b\nC: c\nD: d\nE: e\n",
        "answeris": "B",
        'hint': 'h2'
    }, 
    {
        "question": "333?\nA: a\nB: b\nC: c\nD: d\nE: e\n",
        "answeris": "C",
        'hint': 'h3'
    }, 
    {
        "question": "444?\nA: a\nB: b\nC: c\nD: d\nE: e\n",
        "answeris": "D",
        'hint': 'h4'
    }, 
    { 
        "question": "555?\nA: a\nB: b\nC: c\nD: d\nE: e\n",
        "answeris": "E",
        'hint': 'h5'
    }
]

# POINTS
score = 0

# HINTS
hint = 0

#QUESTIONS
while True: 
  for t in trivia:

    answer = input(t["question"] + "\n\nAnswer: ").upper()

    if answer == t["answeris"]:
        print("Excellent! You are doing freaking great job!\n")
        score = score + 10
    elif answer == "H":
        hint += 1
        if hint > 3:
          print("Sorry! You used all the hints.\n")
          userhint1 = input("Answer: ")
          if userhint1 == t["answeris"]:
            print("Excellent! You are doing great!\n")
            score = score + 10
          else: 
            print("Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is " + t["answeris"] + ".")
            score = score - 10
            
        userhint2 = input(f"* {t['hint']}, there is {3 - hint} hint(s) left. * \n\n Answer: ").upper()
        if userhint2 == t["answeris"]:
          print("Excellent! Keep it up!\n")
          score = score + 10
        else: 
          print("Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is " + t["answeris"] + ".")
          score = score - 10
    else:
        print("Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is " + t["answeris"] + ".")
        score = score - 10 
  def comment_final():
    print("Your score is: " + str(score))
    comment = ["The master of knowledge! You are in the top 1%!!", "Amazing! You are in the top 10%!", "Awesome! You are in the top 30%~", "Good try! You are in the top 50%!", "Don't worry! This was a hard test. Good luck on next time!", "Uh-oh... I think you should have done more studying before taking this test! Try harder next time!"]
    if score == 100:
      print("\n" + comment[0])
    elif score >= 80 and score < 100: 
        print("\n" + comment[1])
    elif score >= 50 and score < 80:
      print("\n" + comment[2])
    elif score >= 0 and score < 50:
      print("\n" + comment[3])
    elif score <= -80 and score < 0:
      print("\n" + comment[4])
    elif score == -100:
      print("\n" + comment[5])
  comment_final()
  lq = input("Play again? (yes/no)")
  if lq == "yes":
    continue
  else: 
    break
```

Can someone tell me what I have done wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You use the name `score` for both the score value and the "score calculator" function. They conflicted. That's all.

Comment: @iBug Oh my god!!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @cherry123 It is quite difficult to 'read' the steps that should be executed by your program due to formatting (e.g., using only 2 spaces as indent, using empty line after `for` and at the same time, not using empty line before and after definition of a function...). Please notice that as presented above, the definition of your function `comment_final()` happens _inside_ the `while`-loop; I suppose it was not your intention to define it again and again. You may want to define the function before the `while`-loop and call it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you post the actual error, it will indicate where the error is taking place in the code. As iBug mentioned, in your case it has to do with `score` being the score value and also the score calculator function.